# How to parse mulitple Json Arrays with the same name in Android

Tags: arrays, json

I want to parse a Json File where all Json Arrays have the same Name:

```
[
   {
      "mobileMachine":{
         "condition":"GOOD",
         "document":"a",
         "idNr":"ce4f5a276a55023efced9c6a4b02bf4fcff04c06b4338467c8679770bff32313f7f372b5ec2f7527dad0de47d0fb117e"
      }
   },
   {
      "mobileMachine":{
         "condition":"GOOD",
         "document":"b",
         "idNr":"ce4f5a276a8e023efced9c6a4b02bf4fcff04c06b4338467c8679770bff32313f7f372b5ec2f7527dad0de47d0fb217e"
      }
   },
   ...
]
```

So here is my little Code:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(urlwhereIGetTheJson);
for (int count = 0; count < json.length(); count++) {
    JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject(count);

    String condition = obj.getString("condition");
    String document = obj.getString("document");
    String idNr = obj.getString("idNr");

    db.addMachine(new MachineAdapter(condition, document, idNr));
}
```

I hope u can show me how to parse the JSON File correctly. Thank you

I can't edit the JSON File. (The File include more than 300 mobilemachines. I have shorten this).

(Sorry for my English)

Comment: What is the problem? The code you provided seems like it should be working fine.

Comment: The code stops at this line:

JSONArray json = new JSONArray(urlwhereIGetTheJson);

This is the Error: 10-28 14:03:34.877: ERROR/InputDispatcher(525): channel '427a5fb8 com.raso/com.am.raso.view.HomeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
10-28 14:03:38.211: ERROR/HttpTransaction(15695): Failed to find the apiHeader field on an http request, this should not happen.
        java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: apiHeader

Comment: This error has got nothing to do with JSON. Check your URL and connection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: You are using the `new JSONArray()` constructor incorrectly. Have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray%28%29). You can not directly pass the url there. You have to obtain it first, and then pass the json to the constructor.

The following piece of code does what you want to do:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
int numMachines = jsonArray.length();

for(int i=0; i<numMachines; i++){
    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    JSONObject machine = obj.getJSONObject("mobileMachine");
    String condition = machine.getString("condition");
    String document = machine.getString("document");
    String idNr = machine.getString("idNr");

    db.addMachine(new MachineAdapter(condition, document, idNr));
}
```

You forgot to obtain the "mobileMachine" json object, and tried to access condition/document/idNr directly.

If you have control over the XML, you could make it smaller by removing the "mobileMachine" node:

```
[
   {
       "condition":"GOOD",
       "document":"a",
       "idNr":"ce4f5a276a55023efced9c6a4b02bf4fcff04c06b4338467c8679770bff32313f7f372b5ec2f7527dad0de47d0fb117e"
   },
   {
       "condition":"GOOD",
       "document":"b",
       "idNr":"ce4f5a276a8e023efced9c6a4b02bf4fcff04c06b4338467c8679770bff32313f7f372b5ec2f7527dad0de47d0fb217e"
   },
   ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonString);
for (int count = 0; count < json.length(); count++) {
   JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject(count).getJSONObject("mobileMachine");


   String condition = obj.getString("condition");
   String document = obj.getString("document");
   String idNr = obj.getString("idNr");

   db.addMachine(new MachineAdapter(condition, document, idNr));
}
```

You forgot "mobileMachine".